# Compile package with java

Tags: java, compilation, javac

I have these programs in java:

```
//file ../src/com/scjaexam/tutorial/GreetingsUniverse.java
package com.scjaexam.tutorial;
public class GreetingsUniverse {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Greetings, Universe!");
        Earth e = new Earth();
    }
}
```

---

```
//file ../src/com/scjaexam/tutorial/planets/Earth.java
package com.scjaexam.tutorial.planets;    
public class Earth {
    public Earth() {
        System.out.println("Hello from Earth!");
    }
}
```

I am able to compile with no error the second one using:

```
javac -d classes src/com/scjaexam/tutorial/planets/Earth.java
```

This puts the compiled file `Earth.class` in the `../classes/com/scjaexam/tutorial/planets/` folder as expected. Now I have to compile the main class `GreetingsUniverse.java` but this command fails:

```
javac -d classes -cp classes src/com/scjaexam/tutorial/GreetingsUniverse.java
```

---

```
src/com/scjaexam/tutorial/GreetingsUniverse.java:7: error: cannot find symbol
        Earth e = new Earth();
        ^
  symbol:   class Earth
  location: class GreetingsUniverse
src/com/scjaexam/tutorial/GreetingsUniverse.java:7: error: cannot find symbol
        Earth e = new Earth();
                      ^
  symbol:   class Earth
  location: class GreetingsUniverse
```

What is the right command to compile (and then tu run) this program?

Comment: Your commands are ok, but in the source code it is nowhere mentioned that Earth is com.scjaexam.tutorial.planets.Earth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to create an instance of the Earth object, however that is in a seperate package meaning it can't find it. You need to import the Earth class in your GreetingsUniverse class using:

```
import com.scjaexam.tutorial.planets.Earth;
```

Comment: So being in a "subpackage" is the same as being in a different package?

Comment: Yes. Sub-packages are only used for organising classes.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't imported the `Earth` class, so the compiler doesn't know what `Earth` refers to. You should have this line at the start of your `GreeingsUniverse.java` file:

```
import com.scjaexam.tutorial.planets.Earth;
```

Comment: So being in a "subpackage" is the same as being in a different package?

Comment: @Red There is no such thing as subpackage in Java. It just happens that your two package names share a common prefix.

Answer (score 1):

You need to import `Earth`:

```
package com.scjaexam.tutorial;

import com.scjaexam.tutorial.planets.Earth;

public class GreetingsUniverse {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Greetings, Universe!");
        Earth e = new Earth();
    }
}
```

When the compiler says `"cannot find symbol: class Earth"`, it is referring to the class you did not import. Be sure to include all packages you use in your class before your class declaration.